# Attachment field is not visible in sharepoint calendar add new event?

Tags: sharepoint, list, calendar

I have a calendar list  and it has the following fields

Title (linked to item)
Description
Location
Start Time
End Time
Facilitator
Total Seat
Available Seat
Edit (link to edit item)
All Day Event
Attachments

I am facing two problems with this list:

1. When I try to add a new event to calendar the Attachment field is not displayed . (attachment filed is from sharepoint by default)
   I tried to make it visible but not happening.
2. after adding an event when I display the added event the date and time is not in a correct format

   ```
   Start Time 2012-02-15T12:30:00Z
   End Time   2012-02-15T13:30:00Z
   ```

How can I format this?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the following for your queries:

1. Make *Attachments to list items* setting is enabled for the Calendar list. For this, go to **List Advanced Settings** from List Settings.
2. Modify 'Regional Settings' of the site as per your requirements. For this, go to *Site Settings* -> *Regional Settings*

Comment: Dear Karthick thank you for the reply , but i have enabled the features you have metioned above.

 This is what you have ment right? 

Attachments Specify whether users can attach files to items in this list. Attachments to list items are: -Add attachments column to default View Enabled

Comment: Still the Attachment field is not visible in the add new form.

Comment: Can you verify the same using 'All Events' view? It will show attachment icon along with list item.

Comment: Thank you karthick . i have got to know the mistake i have done. when i created a new calendar it is working perfectly for the attachment, -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- but for the date still gives me headache. its not coming properly